# Compile error when running simple program

Tags: java

I have a programming assignment where I am asked to write a class named Account with various methods etc. and a test program. I have completed it all but somethings wrong but I cannot figure what it is. Can annyone help me? The program won't compile.

```
import java.util.Date;
public class Account {

    private int id = 0; 
    private double balance = 0;
    private double annualInterestRate = 0;
    private static Date dateCreated = new Date();

    Account(){
        id = 0;
        balance = 0;
        annualInterestRate = 0;
        dateCreated = new java.util.Date();
    }
        Account(int newId, double newBalance, double newAnnualInterestRate){
            id = newId;
            balance = newBalance;
            annualInterestRate = newAnnualInterestRate;

        }

         public int getId(int id){
            return id;
        }

        public int setId(int newId){
            return newId;

        }

        public double getBalance(double balance){
            return balance;
        }

        public double setBalance(double newBalance){
            return newBalance;

        }

        public double getAnnualInterestRate(double newAnnualInterestRate){
        return newAnnualInterestRate;

        }

        public double setAnnualInterestRate(double newAnnualInterestRate){
            return newAnnualInterestRate;

        }

        public Date getDateCreated(Date getDateCreated){
            return dateCreated;
        }

        public double getMonthlyInterestRate(){
            return balance * annualInterestRate / 12;
        }

        public double getMonthlyInterest(double getMonthlyInterestRate){
            return balance * getMonthlyInterestRate;

        }

        public double withdraw(double amount){
            return balance - (balance - amount);
        }

        public double deposit(double amount){
            return (balance + amount) - balance;
        }

    }





public class testAccount {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        Account account = new Account(1122, 20000, 4.5);
            account.setId(1122);
            account.setBalance(20000);
            account.setAnnualInterestRate(4.5);
            account.withdraw(2500);
            account.deposit(3000);
            account.dateCreated();

            System.out.println("Balance is: " + account.balance);

        }


    }
```

Comment: If it doesn't compile than it must have compilation errors?

Comment: What is the exact error you receive?

Comment: `account.balance` private access is not allowed, use the getter.

Comment: Have you ever heard debugging word?

Comment: I would imagine this has something to do with the fact that the `Account` class doesn't have a method named `dateCreated()`...

Comment: *Always* specify the compilation errors when you don't know why something won't compile - and ideally reduce the program down to *just* a minimal example which won't compile. You've provided nearly 100 lines of code here - I suspect that if you removed things bit by bit until you'd got a minimal example, you'd be able to solve the problem yourself.

Comment: your constructors has default access level, are they in same package as your testAccount class?

Comment: Sorry guys. I will remember that in the future. Thank you for your help and fast replies.

Answer (score 2):

Just from glancing at your code, one thing that is wrong is this line:

```
account.dateCreated();
```

You don't have a method named that. You have one named `getDateCreated()`, is that what you meant?

Another problem is this line:

```
account.balance();
```

Again, you probably meant `account.getBalance()`.

Both methods also have required parameters in your code, but they probably shouldn't (as mentioned in the comments by JonK). Getters usually don't take any arguments.

Either way, post the error you are getting.

Comment: Worth mentioning that the `getDateCreated` method that the OP has defined also takes a `Date` parameter (although I have no idea why)

Answer (score 1):

Three problems I can see here:

You can't use `account.balance` as balance has private access in the Account class. This means you can only use this variable in the Account class.
You can either make the balance variable public, or use the `getBalance()` method.

All of the get methods you've declared (`getId` and `getBalance`) will always return the parameter passed to them, and not the actual variable. This is because the parameters has the same name as the instance variable, therefore hiding it.
Typical getters don't have any parameters, so you can get rid of them. If you do need to refer to an instance variable from within a method that has a parameter with the same name, use the `this` keyword (ie `this.balance` refers to the instance variable, `balance` refers to the parameters).

The `dateCreated` method also doesn't seem to exist.

Answer (score 1):

In your print statement, at the end, use account.getBalance().toString()  instead of account.balance

Also get rid of the keyword "public" in public class testAccount.

For your method getDateCreated(Date getDateCreated) you can remove the parameter and instead just use getDateCreated().

when you use account.dateCreated() use account.getDateCreated() instead.

Compile and it should work!